# How to render a webgl in a responsive iframe?

Tags: iframe, three.js, responsiveness

I'm using [ThreeJS](http://threejs.org/) to paint 3D experiments of planets in a `responsive` iframe. Here's an illustration of [Earth](https://bubbl.in/book/responsive-webgl-test-by-marvin-danig/1), for example.

This works fine on `DOMContentLoaded`, but not onresize. The scene is cut off or remains at (0,0) top-left as per its first render. Note, this is the recommended behavior according to [webgl anti patterns](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-anti-patterns.html).

But I want to scale the planet according to the new size of the iframe, both when the window is resized or when `orientation` changes (and leads to a resize). Essentially, to make it cross-platform and responsive.

I have a few ideas to make this work:

Use `innerWidth/innerHeight`, even though it is an [anti-pattern](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-anti-patterns.html), but can work if we dispose() and repaint the scene with new height & width of the iframe.

Ensure the disposition and repaint is carried out efficiently, i.e. setTimeout and detect `resizeFinish()` like so:

```
function resizeFinish() {
  width = window.clientWidth;
  height = window.clientHeight;

  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  render();

  if (scene) {
    while (scene.children.length > 0) {
      scene.remove(scene.children[scene.children.length - 1]);
    }

    // cleanup without calling render (data needs to be cleaned up before a new scene can be generated)
    renderer.dispose(scene.children);
  }

  alertSize();


}
window.onresize = function() {
  clearTimeout(doit);
  doit = setTimeout(function() {
    resizeFinish();
  }, 1000);
};


function render() {
  controls.update();
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.003;
  clouds.rotation.y += 0.005;
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Is this good enough?

Comment: Not a full answer, but try reading http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-anti-patterns.html and see if they work for you.